# rabbitMQ create two separate consumers who consume from two different clusters in the same service

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

i am trying to create two separate consumers who consume from two different clusters in the same service.

i have tried creating new connections but still both the exchange gets created in only one of the clusters.

i am missing something here ? i am using spring-boot:2.2.5.RELEASE and spring-rabbit:2.2.5.RELEASE

My config is something like this.

```js
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

  private final Connection_A_MQProperties connectionAMQProperties;
  private final Connection_B_MQProperties connectionBMQProperties;

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryA(Connection_A_MQProperties connectionAMQProperties) {
    return createConnection(connectionAMQProperties.getBaseProperties());
  }

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryB(Connection_B_MQProperties connectionBMQProperties) {
    return createConnection(connectionBMQProperties.getBaseProperties());
  }

  private ConnectionFactory createConnection(BaseProperties baseProperties){
     CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(baseProperties.getHost());
    factory.setPort(baseProperties.getPort());
    factory.setUsername(baseProperties.getUsername());
    factory.setPassword(baseProperties.getPassword());
    factory.setConnectionTimeout(baseProperties.getConnectionTimeout());
    factory.setRequestedHeartBeat(baseProperties.getRequestedHeartBeat());
    factory.setCacheMode(CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode.CONNECTION);
    factory.setConnectionCacheSize(2);

    return factory;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean("connection_A_RabbitAdmin")
  public RabbitAdmin connection_A_RabbitAdmin(@Qualifier("connection_A_RabbitTemplate") RabbitTemplate connection_A_RabbitTemplate) {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connection_A_RabbitTemplate);

    rabbitAdmin.setExplicitDeclarationsOnly(true);
    return rabbitAdmin;
  }

  @Bean("connection_B_RabbitAdmin")
  public RabbitAdmin connection_B_RabbitAdmin(@Qualifier("connection_B_RabbitTemplate") RabbitTemplate connection_B_RabbitTemplate) {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connection_B_RabbitTemplate);
    rabbitAdmin.setExplicitDeclarationsOnly(true);
    return rabbitAdmin;
  }

  /**
  * each declarable has been configured with a AbstractDeclarable.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare() method which contains the particular admin bean 
  * for which declarable should be processed. i have checked this is getting filtered out correctly for each of the rabbit admins.
  **/

  @Bean("connection_A_Declarable")
  public Declarables connection_A_Declarable(@Qualifier("connection_A_RabbitAdmin") RabbitAdmin connection_A_RabbitAdmin) {
    return DeclarableMQFactory.builder().rabbitAdminList(Collections.singletonList(connection_A_RabbitAdmin))
      .baseProperties(connectionAMQProperties)
      .queueNames(Collections.singletonList(connectionAMQProperties.getQueue()))
      .build();
  }

  @Bean("connection_B_Declarable")
  public Declarables connection_B_Declarable(@Qualifier("connection_B_RabbitAdmin") RabbitAdmin connection_B_RabbitAdmin){
    return DeclarableMQFactory.builder().rabbitAdminList(Collections.singletonList(connection_B_RabbitAdmin))
      .baseProperties(connectionBMQProperties)
      .queueNames(Collections.singletonList(connectionBMQProperties.getQueue()))
      .build();
  }


  @Primary
  @Bean("connection_A_RabbitTemplate")
  public RabbitTemplate connection_A_RabbitTemplate(@Qualifier("connectionFactoryA")ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryA) {
        return rabbitTemplate(connectionFactoryA,connectionAMQProperties);
  }

  @Bean("connection_B_RabbitTemplate")
  public RabbitTemplate connection_B_RabbitTemplate(@Qualifier("connectionFactoryB")ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryB) {
    return rabbitTemplate(connectionFactoryB,connectionBMQProperties);
  }

  private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,BaseProperties baseProperties) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    template.setExchange(baseProperties.getExchange());
    template.setRoutingKey(baseProperties.getQueueName());
    template.setDefaultReceiveQueue(baseProperties.getQueueName());
    return template;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "connection_A_ContainerFactory")
  public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory connection_A_ContainerFactory(@Qualifier("connectionFactoryA")ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryA) {
    return simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(connectionFactoryA,connectionAMQProperties);
  }

  @Bean(name = "connection_B_ContainerFactory")
  public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory connection_B_ContainerFactory(@Qualifier("connectionFactoryB")ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryB){
    return simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(connectionFactoryB,connectionBMQProperties);
  }

  private SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, BaseProperties baseProperties) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(baseProperties.getConcurrentConsumer());
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(baseProperties.getMaxConcurrentConsumer());
    return factory;
  }
}
```

and the listerners are configued as (similar for the second listener)

```js
@RabbitListener(
    queues = "${connection_a.queue}",
    containerFactory = "connectionFactoryA"
  )
```

SOME LOGS(edited to hide some info)(here you can see both exchanges and queues are getting declared correctly with respective admin).

```js
o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: **-**-rabbitmq.qa2-sg.cld:5672
o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: **ConnectionFactory#5cba890e:0/SimpleConnection@513bec8c [delegate=amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/, localPort= 64992]
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Initializing declarations
o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/,1)
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Executing callback RabbitAdmin$$Lambda$1063/0x00000008007e3c40 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@1d6014a7 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@513bec8c [delegate=amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/, localPort= 64992]
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Exchange 'com.**.**.**.connectionA.exchange'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Exchange 'com.**.**.**.connectionA.exchange.DLX'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Queue 'com.**.**.**.**.queue.connectionA.**'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Queue 'com.**.**.**.**.queue.connectionA.**.DLX'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Binding destination [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.** (QUEUE)] to exchange [com.**.**.**.**.exchange] with routing key [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.**]
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Binding destination [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.**.DLX (QUEUE)] to exchange [com.**.**.**.**.exchange.DLX] with routing key [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.**.DLX]
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Declarations finished



o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Starting Rabbit listener container.
o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: message-**-rabbitmq.qa2-sg.cld:5672
o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: **ConnectionFactory#dbca149:0/SimpleConnection@59cb10e0 [delegate=amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/, localPort= 64994]
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Initializing declarations
o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/,1)
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Executing callback RabbitAdmin$$Lambda$1063/0x00000008007e3c40 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@3d763ae5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@59cb10e0 [delegate=amqp://client-user@172.27.**.**:5672/, localPort= 64994]
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Exchange 'com.**.**.**.**.connectionB.exchange'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Exchange 'com.**.**.**.**.connectionB.exchange.DLX'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Queue 'com.**.**.**.**.queue.connectionB.**'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Queue 'com.**.**.**.**.queue.connectionB.**.DLX'
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Binding destination [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.** (QUEUE)] to exchange [com.**.**.**.**.**.exchange] with routing key [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.**]
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Binding destination [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.**.DLX (QUEUE)] to exchange [com.**.**.**.**.**.exchange.DLX] with routing key [com.**.**.**.**.queue.**.**.DLX]
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Declarations finished
```

Comment: Config looks ok. Does DEBUG logging provide any clues?

Comment: i can see that declarables are correctly declared in the logs with the specific connections, but other than that i don't see anything significant related to queue creations. i will add the logs here.

Comment: hi gary, i have updated the logs, my be it can help.

Comment: `>here you can see both exchanges and queues are getting declared correctly with respective admin` - so what's the problem then?

Comment: From logs it seems so but all the exchanges are getting created in only one of the rabbit hosts

Comment: But you said `correctly with respective admin `.

Comment: yes, so there are two rabbit admin which are configured on two different rabbit hosts and i am expecting queues to be created on the respective hosts in the way they are configured to respective admins. from logs it seems that queues are getting configured correctly with the admins but still all the queues are only getting created on one of the hosts.

Comment: That simply makes no sense; sorry; the sentences contradict each other.

Comment: I will try with a sample project and check if it happens there as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected for me:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So62382630Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62382630Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ConnectionFactory cf1() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    }

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory cf2() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("10.0.0.21");
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitAdmin admin1() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(cf1());
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitAdmin admin2() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(cf2());
    }

    @Bean
    Queue q1() {
        Queue queue = new Queue("q1");
        queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin1());
        return queue;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue q2() {
        Queue queue = new Queue("q2");
        queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin2());
        return queue;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitAdmin admin1, RabbitAdmin admin2) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(admin1.getQueueInfo("q1"));
            System.out.println(admin2.getQueueInfo("q2"));
        };
    }

}
```

I see the queues declared on the respective nodes.

Comment: i tried this as well but still exchange/queues are getting created on same host.

Comment: Impossible. You must have something defined incorrectly.